# Set background then inflate layout

Tags: android

I want to inflate a layout to view and then add it to `WindowManager` but before I want to make background of layout to be the same as wallpaper. I've tried this code but sadly `WindowManager` didn't show my new background.Please, help me!!!
My code:

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
rl.setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable); 
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup mTopView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null, true);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setAttributes(params);
    wm.addView(mTopView, params);
```